# Writing CASE statement Error ORA-00923

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I have a database that I have populated using CREATE and INSERT INTO statements. I am now trying to write a CASE statemenet that will display 'customers' whose payment_due_date has passed todays date. Below is the following code

**CREATE STATEMENT 'Ord'(Order)**

```
CREATE TABLE Ord(OrderID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
CustomerID varchar(9) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID), 
Expected_Delivery_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, 
Actual_Delivery_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, 
Payment_Due_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
 Order_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, Price Varchar(10), 
Order_Placed varchar2(1) CONSTRAINT OrderPlaced 
CHECK(Order_Placed IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL, Order_Confirmed varchar2(1)
CONSTRAINT Order_Confirmed CHECK(Order_Confirmed IN('Y','N')) 
NOT NULL, Order_Completed varchar2(1) CONSTRAINT Order_Completed
CHECK(Order_Completed IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL)
```

**INSERT STATEMENT**

```
 INSERT INTO Ord VALUES(401565981, 501623129, 
    '10-Dec-10', '11-Dec-10', '07-Dec-10', '03-Dec-10','£14.99', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')
```

**CASE STATEMENT**

```
 SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, Payment_Due_Date CASE WHEN 
Payment_Due_Date = '08-Dec-10' THEN 'Send Final Demand Letter'
    ELSE 'Do not send letter' 
    END FROM Ord;
```

When I try to run the above case statement I recieve the following error

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found
>   where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 26 Column: 50

Is there any possible way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a comma between Payment_Due_Date and CASE.

Comment: Yip (+1). The result of the CASE-statement is merely another column in your resultset, therefore it needs a comma.

Comment: You can see from the code that I am trying to write a query so that if the Payment due date has past todays date then the query should ouput the message 'Send final demand letter', its fairly similar to an 'if else statement' Payment_Due_Date = <'08-Dec-10' would this work?

Comment: I'd imagine you would need to use `Payment_Due_Date <= '2010-12-08'`, but I don't know that much about Oracle specifics :) (edit: oops, <= instead of >=)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry: I hadn't seen the '08-Dec-10' format before. Your solution is correct.

Comment: @user532339 Argh! Please don't rely on implicit conversion of strings to dates. Ideally use either the to_date function with a format string `to_date('08-DEC-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` or the ANSI date literal `date '2010-12-08'`. Implicit conversion is just asking for trouble!

Comment: MikeyByCrikey, I did use the to_date function and I found that was my problem. Cheers